# Is it possible to apply custom extension to my BIM360docs viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I'm asked to add some function onto the BIM360docs viewer and have already some custom extensions which I made for the Autodesk Forge viewer.

Is there way to apply such forge viewer extension to the BIM360docs viewer?

Comment: unfortunately, it has not been supported to customize the viewer inside BIM360 Docs. Sorry for the bad news

Comment: Thank you for reply. I use a forge viewer for this project.